# UnknowHostException android client socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, ip, host

I am getting the exception java.net.UnknowHostException:http://arbitrary-hero.dyndns.org/. I am attempting to connect to the address with a android client application I have made.

I have two computers one is running ubuntu 10.10 and the other is running windows 7. When I go to www.ipchicken.com on the windows 7 computer to check my ip I get 71.72.220.109 when I do a ifconfig from the command line on my linux machine I get 71.67.105.9. The 71.72.220.109 goes to my server application on the windows 7 computer the 71.67.105.9 and the address arbitrary-hero.dyndns.org goes to the apache server on my ubuntu 10.10 machine. The computers are in the same house using the same network and I dont understand why they have those different addresses. Also I am trying to get them to both use the URL.

```
        String webserver = "71.67.105.9"; //does not work
        String everythingelseinthehouse = "71.72.220.109"; //works
        String weburl = "http://arbitrary-hero.dyndns.org/"; // does not work

        Socket sock = new Socket (weburl , 13267);
        //Socket sock = new Socket (address_everythingelse , 13267);
        //Socket sock = new Socket (address_room , 13267);
```

This is where I declare my socket, sorry about the extra code but I have tried all possible combinations to make this work.

If you would like more code from me to help me solve this problem please ask I would be very happy to resolve this issue.

Comment: Whats the ip address of the server, you are connecting to ?

Comment: What is the address on the server...

Comment: Is it a server with static Ip ?

Comment: My application is on 71.72.220.109                                    My apache server it reporting 71.67.105.9 and my website arbitrary-hero.dyndns.org will only go to the apache server. Also it is not a static ip although I rarely have ever had it change, maybe once in the last 2 years it changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL is not a host name, use `InetAddress.getByName("something.dyndns.org")` instead.

Other stuff about chickens is totally not clear in the question :)

#### Edit 0:

> ... when I do a ifconfig from the command line on my linux machine I get 71.67.105.9 ...

This tells me that your Linux box is either statically configured with this IP, or your router is setup to treat wired connections differently.

Comment: sorry about that let me see if I can break it down better. I have two computers one is running ubuntu 10.10 and the other is running windows 7. When I go to www.ipchicken.com to check my ip I get 71.72.220.109 when I do a ifconfig from the command line on my linux machine I get 71.67.105.9. The 71.72.220.109 goes to my server application on the windows 7 computer the 71.67.105.9 and the address arbitrary-hero.dyndns.org got the apache server on my ubuntu 10.10 machine. The computers are in the same house using the same network and I dont understand why they have those different addresses.

Comment: How do those two machines connect to the internet? (explain where the wires go :)

Comment: The Ubuntu 10.10 is connected via a hardline to the router. The Windows 7 machine is connected to the router wirelessly. Also the client is my android phone not on the local network.

Comment: It looks like the two machines are grabbing DHCP leases directly from your ISP, i.e. the router is probably setup in some sort of "bridge" mode.

Comment: They also have local addresses though the ubuntu 10.10 is 192.168.1.6 and the windows 7 is 192.168.1.4. Also ever computer in the house is  71.72.220.109 except for the ubuntu 10.10 which is 71.67.105.9.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you connect to the same router over wireless? Can it be some neighbor's access point by any chance?

Comment: I am sure that I am connected to my router. Under the routers gui it shows my windows 7 computer and my Ubuntu 10.10 computer.

Comment: Some weird stuff in Cincinnati :) Can you try different "my ip" sites?

Comment: yeah I have tried a few different sites I they all give me the 71.72.220.109.

Comment: I know this is from a long time ago but I found out the linux box is statically configured. I moved it to another location and am now receiving the same ip address.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this premission to `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

---

Also, you need to use `InetAddress` for using the domain name instead of the IP address:

```
Socket sock = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(weburl) , 13267);
```

Comment: I already had the permission added and I tried using InetAddress and still received the same error.